# Unable to Start File Server Resource Manager on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, resource-management, file-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 (RTM) 32-bit box configured for File Services Role.  I installed the File Server Resource Manager feature on the server.  When I try to use the snap-in, it gives me the error:

> Unable to connect to FSRM on computer
> \\(local machine). This can happen if
> the remote computer does not have the
> Windows Server 2008 or later version
> of FSRM installed, or if a connection
> cannot be established because it was
> blocked by Windows Firewall.
>
> Choose 'Connect to another computer' to manage a different computer running Windows server 2008 or later.

I know there is some stuff out on the Interweb about a bad dll, but that seems to apply only to Server 2003.  That dll does not exist on 2008.  Has anyone experienced this issue and discovered a fix?

Firewalls are turned off via Group Policy (our network is completely isolated from the Internet).  DFS is working in all other respects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the FRSM via role services and not under add features.  Add features only installs the management interface and not the actual service.

Comment: Absoultely brilliant.  Your answer was spot on!